# Optimal matching with caliper in MatchIt package in R?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

I am using the package `MatchIt` in R to perform propensity score matching. The command is

```
m = matchit(T ~ age + sex + ibs + piks, data=d, method="optimal", 
            distance="logit", caliper=.2)
```

As a result I get 0.38 as the difference of the mean propensity scores in the treatment and control groups. Thus the caliper option seems to be ignored.

How can I specify a caliper option for optimal matching?

Answer (score 2):

When using optimal matching caliper is ignored. This is explicitly defined at the bottom of page 35 for the matchit package documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue that has been mentioned previously, but no solutions:

https://lists.gking.harvard.edu/pipermail/matchit/2014-July/000583.html

Comment: While this link may provide a solution to the question it would be better to have the content directly in your answer. Links change or may become invalid over time in which case your answer will not be useful to future readers.

Comment: Hi Andy, the point of the message was that there was no solution to the above question, and that it has been mentioned previously. I've checked again, but there does not seem to be a solution available for calipers for optimal matching with MatchIt.